# Android Instrumentation Test get resource file handle

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-instrumentation

To test one of my implementations I need a valid and correctly initialised File-Object that points to an image file.

I've tried the following:

- placed an image into the androidTest/ressources-Folder named cat.jpeg
- tried to create a file handle the following way: `new File(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getClassLoader().getResource(“cat.jpg”).getPath())`

when calling `exists()` on the initialized file it always returns false.

How do I have to setup the test / initialize the file to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to put all the test resources in `androidTest/assets`. By fetching the `AssetManager` from the test package's context, you can get the assets as a list of filenames (`AssetManager.list(String path)`). For each asset, open an `InputStream` with `AssetManager.open(String filename)` and create a temporary file that you write the asset to.